# Capture which shape was clicked on in powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint presentation in which some slides contain multiple shapes for the user to click on.

I want to capture which shape is clicked. I am able to capture if the shape has text on it by using a macro, but what if such shape contains an image?

Comment: If the shape has no text for you to check then check its name instead.

Answer (score 0):

Every shape on a slide has a unique ID property that you can examine to determine which shape is selected.

Or you can add a tag to the shape beforehand:

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Tags.Add "MyName", "MyValue"
```

then

```
If ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Tags("MyName") = "MyValue" Then
   ' Whatever
```